# Vite proxy to https "Error: unable to get local issuer certificate:

Tags: vite

I have the following as my `vote.config.ts`:

```js
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  define: {
    // global: {},
  },
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      root: "/",
      src: "/src",
      server: "/server",
    },
  },
  server: {
    port: 3000,
    proxy: {
      "/api": "https://backend.someserver.io/api",
    },
  },
});
```

And calls to the `localhost:3000/api/any/api/endpoint` end up in the terminal with the following error:

```
Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1550:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:967:8)
    at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:743:12) (x2)
```

How do I get it to proxy to the https endpoint?